# Is SQL query execution a part of TTFB?

Tags: database-connection, pageload, page-load-time, server-response

I am facing an issue with a load time of a web page where the page loads in around 1.5 min and TTFB is close to 1.2 min.

What I see is that the database table has 17k rows which can be a reason of this slowness.

But TTFB refers to the amount of time it takes a browser to create a connection to the server and start downloading the contents of a web page.

So is SQL query execution also a part of TTFB ?
Note : I am running the website on Windows server 2012 R2 with SQL server 2016 database.

Comment: 17k row is a pretty small number, it should take below a few seconds to fetch on an average pc. I guess you may have some cross-join-equivalent  join in your query.

Comment: Yeah even I think so..and those are also filtered by indexes..